# Exclude elections from array_rand

Tags: php, random

I found this php code which generates randomdly selects a value between 1 and 9, but excludes those in the array $exclude. IT WORKS.

```
$exclude = array(1,2,3);
while(in_array(($x = rand(1,9)), $exclude));
echo $x;
```

Now I want to select one of the letters in the array $items (from 'a' to 'h'), but excluding those in $exclude (from 'a' to 'c'). I use the following code:

```
$items = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h");
$exclude = array("a", "b", "c");
$rkey = array_rand($items);
while(in_array(($election = $items[$rkey]), $exclude));
echo $election;
```

**PROBLEM:** This works, but after refreshing a number of times, the browser stops working and keeps loading indefinitely. It does not display any error.

Comment: I don't have a clue, I'm working with XAMPP. Couldn't it be a problem of my code?

Comment: In your working example the random number is redrawn on every iteration of the loop. In your second code you draw a random letter once, and use that in the loop forever. If it's the wrong letter you will loop forever.... and ever....

Comment: It's also entirely possible that `array_rand()` will select one of your "excluded" items every single time, forever. "Random" does not mean "fair". To avoid wasting a lot of time in loops like this, copy `$items` to a temporary location, _remove_ the "excluded" items, and select a random entry from _that_.

Comment: As Kiko said, move the random into the loop. You can switch to a `do` loop which will guarantee that it runs at least once: https://3v4l.org/ecsEK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or a simpler way to do this is to use the inbuilt PHP function named [array_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) which returns a new list of items by removing (returning difference) existing items from the main list, as:

```
$items = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h");
$exclude = array("a", "b", "c");

$nItems = array_diff($items, $exclude);
$rkey = array_rand($nItems);

$election = $nItems[$rkey];
```

Answer (score 1):

`$rkey` is only evaluated once. You can substitute the code into the `while` loop:

```
<?php

$items = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h");
$exclude = array("a", "b", "c");
while(in_array(($election = $items[array_rand($items)]), $exclude));
echo $election;
```

[Teh Playground!](https://www.tehplayground.com/B2yQiit1kJvuhsnr)

Note that PHP has the [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) inbuilt function which does the same thing.

```
$arrDiff=array_diff($items,$exclude);
echo $arrDiff[array_rand($arrDiff)];
```